# Sitecore GetQueryable Filter not returning any result for SOLR after switch from Lucene

Tags: solr, lucene, sitecore, sitecore8

I'm in process of switching the Sitecore Lucene Search provider to Solr. Cores have been configured and I can rebuild all the COREs with no problem.

I also updated the computed index fields per Solr mapping requirements. However, for weird reason the query below isn't returning any results.

```
using (var context = index.CreateSearchContext(SearchSecurityOptions.DisableSecurityCheck))
            {

                var query = context.GetQueryable<ArticleSearchResultItem>().Filter(item => item.Category == categoryId);

                var results = query.GetResults();
}
```

But when I do this I can match the categoryid i.e. I can hit inside if condition.

```
using (var context = index.CreateSearchContext(SearchSecurityOptions.DisableSecurityCheck))
            {
                var query1 = context.GetQueryable<ArticleSearchResultItem>();
                foreach (var q in query1)
                {
                    if (q.Category == categoryId)
                    {
                        //Matched Category ID
                    }
                }

}
```

The second test above confirms that:

1. I am getting data from SOLR
2. And the result has matching categoryId

But I just don't understand why the first one doesn't match it!!

Will appreciate if you could review my POCO and field mapping below:

Field Mapping:

```
<fields hint="raw:AddComputedIndexField">
              field fieldName="articlecategory" returnType="string">MyNameSpace.ComputedFields.ArticleCategoryField, MyNameSpace.Business</field>
              ....
```

POCO:

```
public class ArticleSearchResultItem : BaseSearchItem
    {
        [IndexField("articlecategory")]
        [TypeConverter(typeof(IndexFieldIDValueConverter))]
        public ID Category { get; set; }
        }
```

Noticed below on Search.log

23732 2016:01:23 22:49:46 INFO Serialized Query - ?q=articlecategory_s:(e83405719a5c4ff18595d685c9103e0f)&rows=2147483647&fl=*,score&fq=_indexname:(sitecore_web_index)

Tried copy paste the query below on to Solr Admin, nothing gets returned.

```
?q=articlecategory_s:(e83405719a5c4ff18595d685c9103e0f)&rows=2147483647&fl=*,score&fq=_indexname:(sitecore_web_index)
```

Comment: Try examining the contents of the index in the Web UI. You can drop that by using the 'core selector' dropdown, then I think it's 'Query' in the left menu or something like that. Query by setting the 'q' param with a json object.

Answer (score 2):

Managed to resolve this issue..

The issue was that computed index field had a logic where ID was converted to short guid.

I removed this line and re-indexed and started getting data from SOLR.